# SQL Server 2005 won't install Error 29503

Tags: sql-server-2005, installation

I'm having issues installing Sql Server 2005 Express Edition on a Acer laptop. The laptop is running XP service pack 3 and an Intel Core 2 Duo processor.
Here are the full specs for the machine http://www.premiumgeeks.com/laptop/acer-laptop/acer-extensa-5620-specs/

The error:

> Error 29503 The SQL Server service failed to start. For more information, see the SQL Server Books Online topics, "How to: View SQL Server 2005 Setup Log Files" and "Starting SQL Server Manually"

Relevant part of the log file:

```
<Func Name='GetCAContext'>
<EndFunc Name='GetCAContext' Return='T' GetLastError='203'>
Doing Action: Do_sqlScript
PerfTime Start: Do_sqlScript : Mon Jan 31 09:42:16 2011
Service MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS with parameters '-m SqlSetup -Q
   -qSQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS -T4022 -T3659 -T3610 -T4010'
  is being started at Mon Jan 31 09:42:16 2011
```

There was also something in the eventviewer about performance counters not being enabled for SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What user did you choose for SQL Service? You could try administrator user.

Comment: It was using the network service account. Tried using the Local System account and all is well. Grrrr, struggled my ass of with this and just as I posted the question solved it about 5 minutes later. Thanks for your response Lorenzo, It would have solved the problem too.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, try disabling any anti-virus.